# querying and creating folders/files from within a library

Tags: apex, files

I have a library called Test, which has a folder in it called 123. The folder contains a single pdf file.

[image]

I'm able to successfully query that file using the following SOQL statement.

```
SELECT Id, Title, FileExtension FROM ContentFolderItem WHERE ParentContentFolderId IN (SELECT Id FROM ContentFolder WHERE Name = '123')
```

Is there anyway to add to this query the condition to include the library name `Test`?

I was able to create the library, folder, and upload the pdf using the UI. How can I do all that with apex?

This is what I've done in my test code, but I can't navigate the relationships of all the sObjects involved.

```
    // create Library
    System.runAs ( new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId()) ) {
        ContentWorkspace cw = new ContentWorkspace();
        cw.Name = 'Test';

        insert cw;        
    }

    // creat file
    ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
    cv.Title = 'dummy';
    cv.PathOnClient = 'dummy.pdf';
    cv.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('test');

    insert cv;

     // create folder. There is no clear way to add this folder to a library using apex...
     ContentFolder f = new ContentFolder();
     f.Name = '123';

     insert f;
```

Then there needs to be some dml usage using [ContentFolderItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentfolderitem.htm) and [ContentFolderLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentfolderlink.htm?search_text=Content) I believe...

After creating a folders, I've tried this code:

```
    ContentWorkspace cw = [SELECT Id FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = 'Test'];


    Database.SaveResult[]  results = Database.insert(folders, true);

    List<ContentFolderLink> folderLinks = new List<ContentFolderLink>();

    for(Database.SaveResult r : results) {
        if(r.isSuccess()) {
            ContentFolderLink cfl = new ContentFolderLink();
            cfl.EnableFolderStatus = 'S';
            cfl.ParentEntityId = cw.Id;
            cfl.ContentFolderId = r.Id;

            folderLinks.add(cfl);    
        }
    }
```

put I get a bunch of `Field is not writeable` errors.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue and turns out that there are some additional objects that support linking documents into a specific folder.

The ContentDocumentLink will share the documents to the workspace and automatically create ContentFolderMember records.  In order to push those records into a sub-folder within the workspace, *you have to query and update those existing records*.  Trying to create new ContentFolderMember records will result in a duplicate error.

To put it all together, it would look something like this:

```
@testSetup
private static void createTestData() {
    ContentWorkspace testWorkspace = new ContentWorkspace(Name='TEST CLASS', DeveloperName='TEST_CLASS');
    insert testWorkspace;
}

@isTest
private static void testGetFilesList(){
    ContentWorkspace testWorkspace = [Select Id from ContentWorkspace where Name = 'TEST CLASS'];

    ContentFolder workspaceFolder = [Select Id from ContentFolder where Name =: testWorkspace.Id];

    ContentFolder testFolderRecord = new ContentFolder(Name='TEST FOLDER', ParentContentFolderId=workspaceFolder.Id);
    insert testFolderRecord;

    List<ContentVersion> contentVersions = new List<ContentVersion>();

    for(Integer i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        String fileExtension = '';
        Switch on i {
            when 1 {
                fileExtension='csv';
            }
            when 2 {
                fileExtension='jpg';
            }
            when 3 {
                fileExtension='gif';
            }
            when 4 {
                fileExtension='tiff';
            }
            when 5 {
                fileExtension='ppt';
            }
            when 6 {
                fileExtension='xls';
            }
            when 7 {
                fileExtension='xlsx';
            }
            when 8 {
                fileExtension='doc';
            }
            when 9 {
                fileExtension='docx';
            }
            when 10 {
                fileExtension='pdf';
            }
            when 11 {
                fileExtension='pptx';
            }
            when else {
                fileExtension='json';
            }
        }

        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.title = 'test content'+i;        
        cv.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body'+i);
        cv.PathOnClient = 'test content'+i+'.'+fileExtension;
        contentVersions.add(cv);
    }

    insert contentVersions;

    List<ContentDocumentLink> documentLinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
    List<ContentFolderMember> folderMembers = new List<ContentFolderMember>();

    for(ContentVersion cv : [Select Id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion]) {
        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
        cdl.ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId;
        cdl.LinkedEntityId = testWorkspace.Id;   
        cdl.Sharetype = 'I';
        documentLinks.add(cdl);
    }

    insert documentLinks;

    for(ContentFolderMember cfm : [Select Id, ChildRecordId, ParentContentFolderId
                                   from ContentFolderMember
                                   where ParentContentFolderId =: workspaceFolder.Id]) {
        cfm.ParentContentFolderId = testFolderRecord.Id;
        folderMembers.add(cfm);
    }

    update folderMembers;
}
```

(You can ignore the file extension piece, just optional to mimic adding different types of files)

This answer also provides some context: [Upload File in ContentFolder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224567/upload-file-in-contentfolder)